# Conversion of constant C to $\ln{A}$ after integration

Tags: integration

I am working on the question 'Describe the family of curves represented by the differential equation $y = x \frac{dy}{dx}$ and sketch any three members of the family.'

Collecting the terms and integrating both sides results in:

$\ln{y} = \ln{x} + K$ where $K$ is the constant of integration. This would result in a family of straight-lines that are translated long the y axis.

However, the answer can also be stated as:

$\ln{y} = \ln{x} + \ln{A}$

$y = xA$

Now this results in a family of straight lines radial around the origin.

I always thoguht the specification of the cosntant was fairly arbitary, but this compeltely changes the result, and I can't reconcile this. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Log properties: $e^{\ln A}$ equals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We exponentiate both sides of $$\ln(y)=\ln(x)+K$$ to get $$y=e^{\ln(x)+K}=xe^{K},$$ which is the same type of multiplicative constant as you have in the other case, with $e^K=A$. You can't treat $\ln(y)$ and $\ln(x)$ like $y$ and $x$ when determining the family of curves that the first equation corresponds to.